# Is there a way to have code templates for "if", "for" (or) for any multiline commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line, template

Code templates are handy and help in finishing codes without error.

I am aware that notepad editors like atom provide code templates for `if` and `for` loop for bash.

Also aware that `man` pages provide assistance in understanding the syntax. For e.g., `man $SHELL` helps to understand the `if` and `for` commands.

But, I was wondering if there is a way to bring code templates into a terminal itself rather than using a code editor? This will help us to be more productive.

Let me give a use case scenario.

[For this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238371/conditional-statement-in-bash-script/) to be solved, I wanted to have a `for` loop and then a `if` loop encased in that.

So if a template for `for` loop can be generated by some shortcuts in the terminal such that

```
for i in **type words here**; do 

    **type words here** 

done
```

Then I go inside the for loop template and then click another shortcut for the ```if````

```
for i in **type words here**; do 

    if [ **type words here**]; then
       **type words here**     
    fi

done
```

Comment: Clarification: I previously posted this question in askUbuntu forum. As I got no reply. I deleted that post and then posting in Unix and Linux forum. So have posted in only one place of StackExchange.

Comment: There is a _similar_ feature in some shells called something like "suggestions" (programmable suggestion? automatic suggestion? I can't remember). I think this may be enabled in `zsh` and in `fish`. It uses the shell history to find something similar to what you're currently typing. It's definitely not what you're asking for, but, as I said, it's similar.

Comment: zsh has autosuggestion feature. Aware of it.